# Detect when BLE scanning over 5 times in 30 seconds

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

[This article](https://blog.classycode.com/undocumented-android-7-ble-behavior-changes-d1a9bd87d983) says that android BLE can just scan 5 times per 30 seconds. The 6th time it fails. My problem is that I could not fetch this issue. It seems that there is no exception or anything else.

The `onScanFailed` is not called with this error. It seems to be silent.

```
   private val scanCallback = object: ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode)
            // not called 
        }
    }
```

I tried to register for `ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED` But this action is only called when you use `BLEAdapter.getInstance().startDiscovery()` And this command is for classic bluetooth. I use the scan for BLE.

The same is true for the following attribute: `BLEAdapter.getInstance().isDiscovering` This can only be true, when you use `startDiscovery`

Does anyone have any idea how I can find out if scanning is failing because it is the 6th time in 30 seconds?

Comment: I suggest you use the complete official documentation here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview#basics. I'm currently creating an Android app that can scan, pair, and communicate with BLE devices. I'm using the documentation and it works.

Comment: That's not my problem. My app works, too. The problem is how I could handle/fetch more than 5 scan connections in 30 seconds.

Comment: In my case the scans are refreshed on pull to refresh. So what we did was to start a count and when the count reaches 5 times of pull. we are showing a toast to try after sometimes.  The result is getting refreshed after sometimes. using this  way.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the API does not report when you reach the limit. You need to keep track of yourself how often and when you scan.

Otherwise it looks like the scan is ongoing, while in fact it is not.

You however see in the logcat log when the limit is reached.